# Parsing JSON response using Citrus framework for URLEncode

Tags: parsing, frameworks, response

I'm using Citrus to automate our RESTful services where service1's input param is passed onto service2' input after URLEncoding.

Below is the code snippet, to explain the ways I tried but somehow unable to URLEncode, on top of designer.traceVariables().

Owing to the limitation (possible known!) that the response params can't be passed outside of context, I had to call multiple send(), receive() calls, defined in the same Gherkin method as below. 
I'm able to print the variable myVar (extracted from payLoad) using designer.traceVariables() but unable to process & persist it for further use, to pass onto the next service call.

```
@When("^I call CPAuth service for ChasePay$")
public void i_call_CPAuth_service_for_ChasePay() throws Throwable {
    designer.send("CitrusContext")
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .header(X_JPMC_CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER, csrfToken)
    .header(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header(COOKIE, ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY + "=" + proxy)
    .header("citrus_endpoint_uri", authUrl +"/auth/fcc/login")
    .message(new HttpMessage("<large_string=no_issues_here>").method(HttpMethod.POST));

    designer.receive("CitrusContext").messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .validate("$.response", "secauth")
    .validate("$.newstoken", false)
    .validate("$.smtoken", "void")
    .extractFromPayload("$.spid", "myVar");

    String request = URLEncoder.encode("appStoreBundleId=com.testmerchant.sampleapp&version=APP%2BBUILD%2BVERSION&channelId=MPD&spid=**${myVar}**&type=json&chasePayMerchantId=1390xxx", CharEncoding.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("request: "+request);
    designer.send("CitrusContext")
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .header(X_JPMC_CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER, csrfToken)
    .header(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header(COOKIE, ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY + "=" + proxy)
    .header("citrus_endpoint_uri", hostUrl +"/pwc/provisioning/pos/otp/contact/v20160313/list.action")
    .message(new HttpMessage(request).method(HttpMethod.POST));
```

Result: 
Before encoding: MSZp2V/czcKsxej+Q04Da/QeVlo=MCwCFAqrBN/6/J8WZENecE7JQlEODnecAhQCcnXGBjMoiQ7deunlyXKacFo/lQ== (This should be the string, to be encoded.) 
After encoding: %3D%24%7BmyVar%7D%26

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The encode operation destroys the "${myVar}" expression before Citrus is able to parse and interpret the expression as part of the message payload. You need to execute the encode operation as a Citrus function. How to write this function is described here: http://citrusframework.org/docs/custom-functions/

You end up having something like:

```
designer.send("CitrusContext")
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .message(new HttpMessage("custom:urlEncode('appStoreBundleId=com.testmerchant.sampleapp&version=APP%2BBUILD%2BVERSION&channelId=MPD&spid=**${myVar}**&type=json&chasePayMerchantId=1390xxx')").method(HttpMethod.POST));
```